# ElasticSearch json objects

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, elasticsearch

The front-end is an angular [dynamic-form](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms) and the back-end is spring boot with connection in mysql and Elasticsearch. The form(JSON type) is stored in mysql 8. I want to make Elasticsearch queries in the field/variable in specific fields of form using either hibernate-search or any other sugggested technic

```
public class UserForm {
...
@Type(type = "json")
private String form;
....
}
```

Also the form-JSON structure will be different like

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "zipCode": "13561",
      "state": "attiki",
      "city": "agioi anargiroi"
    },
    {
      "zipCode": "10432",
      "state": "attiki",
      "city": "athens"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or

```
{
  "firstName": "thanos",
  "lastName": "keske",
  "email": "thanos.keske@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: my question is if I can make queries like {"match" :{"array.zipCode":13561}} [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html). I want a workarround when I save the json form (java-hibernate to mysql) make a proper indexing to elasticsearch